# How to convert mesh primitive from Quads to Tris?

Tags: mesh, export, polycount

I have a mesh that was sculpted in Quads but am trying to use it in an engine that expects Tris. How can I convert the mesh within blender (or the engine) into a Tri mesh?

[image]

Comment: Apart from the link that @brockmann has given where you can find your answer - since you know the engine expects tris, which format would you use to export the mesh from Blender? Because some formats automatically convert quads to tris, you can easily check it within Blender if you simply export it and then re-import it in Blender.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Good question. We are not using an common fromats like .obj, .fbx etc which you might be alluding to. We are doing raw import of the blender file and binary parsing so we need the blender file in order.

Comment: In all respect just from curiosity ... may I ask you - what make it difficult to discover this feature inside blender or found it straightforward on a net? Thank you